# Maximum number of cosigners on a home loan?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, california, home-loan, mortgage-qualification

Is there a "maximum" allowed number of cosigners on a home loan? I notice there are some areas with very nice homes large enough for even multiple families to comfortably live in, however as expected those properties are also correspondingly much more expensive as well.

So, is there a limit as to how many cosigners can sign up for a single home loan in that case? If anything, at least for mortgage payment splitting purposes...

Comment: What country & state are you asking about? Laws and regulations vary.

Comment: For location or legal reference, just looking across a few regions around my home state of California (e.g., the Bay Area, Los Angeles area, etc...)

Comment: Why should there be a limit? When it comes to banks, there can never be enough cosigners on a loan, because every cosigner is an additional contingency to get the money from if the main signer goes bankrupt.

Comment: they might be concerned that the number of signers could increase the number of disagreements when decisions have to be made. They also may view it as a business not a personal loan. In addition because the question mentions multiple families, they may be concerned that the living arrangements are in violation of local zoning that limit the number of unrelated people living in a single family residence.  I have know idea if this is true, they are just possible concerns.

Comment: Keep in mind HOA restrictions could preclude multiple families living in the same residence.  This certainly is the case in my HOA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://finance.zacks.com/many-names-can-mortgage-9494.html), yes - it is *possible* for more than 2 people to co-sign on a mortgage. There is no "maximum" as each mortgage application is unique and different. As a result, it is all dependent on the mortgage company, and your unique situation.

> In some cases, a lender will allow more than two borrowers to sign
>   onto a mortgage contract. This is a rarer occurrence and usually
>   applies only when a clear lack of income exists between two people on
>   a mortgage application. A third party can enter the agreement and use
>   her income to support the loan application. However, if a third
>   person's income is used to calculate the debt-to-income ratio on the
>   loan application, the third person is obligated to the repayment of
>   loan over the course of its amortization.

However, there is a difference between being on the mortgage and being on the deed. Being on the mortgage does not automatically mean you own the home, it only means you are [financially obligated](https://budgeting.thenest.com/many-applicants-allowed-mortgage-31593.html) to pay the loan.

> While all co-owners of the property are required to apply for or
>   consent to the loan, you can add non-owners to the application as
>   well. A co-signer on the mortgage isn’t directly liable for the loan.
>   Rather, he is a backup in case you fail to meet your obligation to
>   repay. To apply as a co-signer, the person or persons who have no
>   ownership in the property must fill out the application with you and
>   provide proof of income and authorization to run their credit. There
>   usually isn’t a limit on the number of co-signers you can have,
>   provided the co-signer is willing to be on the hook for the loan.